# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-inflate

Use eclipse.

I want use google map on my app.
when i run app on genymotion emulator logcut show error :android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment.

I add google-play-services_lib in eclipse and add it in library.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (initMap()) {
//              mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gmapsapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application> 

</manifest>
```

activity_map:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

logcat :

```
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.example.gmapsapp/com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:360)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1932)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    ... 11 more
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.g.a(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ab.a(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aa.a(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
12-14 23:09:15.781: E/AndroidRuntime(29819):    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29819): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

As the error indicates, your manifest is missing the `<meta-data>` element for the API key:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
       android:value="Please type in your API key here, replacing this stub value"/>
```